# Como obter os itens que várias listas têm em comum

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, set

Como fazer para quando não houver um item comum, lançar avisos?

Lista 1, 2 e 3 tem números diferentes de índices.

```
def compabilitySorter (lista1, lista2, lista3):

    listCompatible=[lista1, lista2, lista3]


    checkedItem=set()
    commonItem=set()

    for i in listCompatible:
        for j in i:

            if j in checkedItem:
                commonItem.add(j)
            else:

                checkedItem.add(j)

    return list(commonItem)
```

Exemplo 1 (Output pretendido):

```
print(compabilitySorter([1, 2, 4],[2],[2, 3, 6]))
>[2]
```

Quando não existe um item comum, lança uma lista com números que não tem a haver com a resposta pretendida.

Exemplo 2 (Output não pretendido):

```
print(compabilitySorter([1, 2, 4],[3, 5],[2, 3, 6]))
>[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Itens em comum" na teoria de conjuntos é chamado [interseção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interse%C3%A7%C3%A3o). No python, os sets (cuja a tradução é literamente "conjuntos") possuem operadores e métodos prontos para você utilizar.

Neste caso você pode utilizar o método [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) ou o operador [`&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) para realizar a interseção entre 2 ou mais conjuntos.

```
conjunto_1 = {1, 2, 3}
conjunto_2 = {2, 3, 4}
conjunto_3 = {3, 4, 5}

print(conjunto_1 & conjunto_2 & conjunto_3)
# >>> {3}

# ou também
print(conjunto_1.intersection(conjunto_2, conjunto_3))
# >>> {3}
```

---

Para testar se a interseção é vazia basta testar a lista resultante diretamente, pois coleções e sequências vazias, quando convertidas para boolean, são `False` ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).

```
print('True' if [] else 'False')  # False
print('True' if [0] else 'False') # True
```

---

Então seu código poderia ser apenas:

```
def compatibilitySorter(lista1, lista2, lista3):
    set1, set2, set3 = set(lista1), set(lista2), set(lista3)
    return list(set1 & set2 & set3)
```

Usando seus exemplos para testar:

```
teste1 = compatibilitySorter([1, 2, 4], [2], [2, 3, 6])
print('Interseção:', teste1)

if not teste1:
    print('Interseção vazia, lançar erro...')

print('-' * 15)

teste2 = compatibilitySorter([1, 2, 4], [3, 5], [2, 3, 6])
print('Interseção:', teste2)

if not teste2:
    print('Interseção vazia, lançar erro...')
```

A saída seria:

```
Interseção: [2]
---------------
Interseção: []
Interseção vazia, lançar erro...
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-349569-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>